# Multi database transaction - How to handle transaction while writing to DynamoDB and Oracle

Tags: oracle, transactions, amazon-dynamodb

I have a requirement to save to write to Amazon DynamoDB and a couple of tables in Oracle database in the same transaction.

What is the right approach to handle this requirement?
1. shall i use JTA like Atomikos.
2. Another suggestion i received is to save to oracle but do not commit, 
and the write to DynamoDB & commit to oracle in case write to DynamoDB succeeds otherwise rollback the transaction.

Any other thoughts on this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: second wont work since in dynamodb there is not concept of rollback. in short transaction across two independent disjoint system is not possible. the best you can do is reduce the probability of error

Comment: Yeah...  To reduce the possibility of error is the aim behind second approach. I am trying to find out if there is any better way of doing this.